# How do I save API data (a converted object) into an SQL server in a console application

Tags: c#, sql, .net, api, restsharp

I've managed to build a console application that successfully requests API data and converts it into a JSON object. However, I don't know how to put these DTO files (recently stored API objects) into my SQL server.

So far I have this for the console application.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            getRequestData();
        } 

        public static void getRequestData()
        {
            var client = new RestClient(URL);
            var request = new RestRequest();
            var response = client.Execute(request);

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string rawResponse = response.Content;
                AllRequests.Rootobject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllRequests.Rootobject>(rawResponse);
            }
        } 
    }
```

As you can see, the console application program.cs file successfully obtains a get request then converts the API data into an object (A Json object I think). Here is the DTO file (AllRequests) that the data is being saved into.

```
class AllRequests
    {
        public class Rootobject
        {
            public Operation operation { get; set; }
        }

        public class Operation
        {
            public Result result { get; set; }
            public Detail[] details { get; set; }
        }

        public class Result
        {
            public string message { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
        }

        public class Detail
        {
            public string requester { get; set; }
            public string workorderid { get; set; }
            public string accountname { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

When testing the application in debug mode, the objects are stored correctly and everything is fine. However, I don't know how to save these objects into an SQL database. I do already have an SQL server, however, I'm not sure how to push the already converted data and save it into a retrospective table. So for instance, saving this data into a Request table in my SQL database.

At the moment I only know how to make API calls in this console application. I can't find any data that will assist me with completing the second part of this task, which is storing the data into an SQL database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, apologise if there is too much unnecessary information.

Comment: You can store an "object" as datatype `binary` in a database. However if this is JSON then you would typically "serialise" it into a string and just save the string into a `varchar` datatype. You should confirm what kind of object this is. In fact most objects can be "serialised" - effectively converted to a string representation. Even pictures can be serialised.

Comment: In fact... before you call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` the JSON data is already serialised, so you can just save that directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few methods to make your application interact with a Database. You can setup your application to use [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) (EF) to manage your DB. It is a powerfull and very popular [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping); there are a lot of resources in the web for help.

Personaly, I like to work with [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/), that is very simple to use in comparison with EF. You just have to provide your connection-string to create your SqlConnection object.

You can find a simple tutorial in this [link](https://dapper-tutorial.net/step-by-step-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

I avoid EF and other tools frankly. Just more hills to learn.

In .Net 6, I use `RestSharp` to do the API calls and conversion to JSON and `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` to save the data into SQL Server.

Get your API call to respond

```
var client = new RestClient("your API url");;
```

Apply the API call

```
var req = new RestRequest();
req.AddHeader("x-api-key", "your API key");
```

Get a response object in JSON by default

```
RestResponse resp = client.Execute(req);
```

Make sure it worked

```
if (resp.IsSuccessful) {}
```

Deserialise your response, where RootObject is my name for my SQL Server table schema as a Class

```
            RootObject ro = new RootObject();
            ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(resp.Content);
```

Build a List<>

```
            //iterate through each device data and add it into a DataRow
            List<DeviceClass> device = new List<DeviceClass>();
            DataTable dt = GenericList2Datatable<DeviceClass>(device);

            //only do anything if the API call worked!
            if (!dt.HasErrors)
            {
                foreach (Device d in ro.Devices)
                {
```

here do your mapping from "ro" object over to data objects like DataRow and DataTable and put them across to SQL server further down. Plenty on the web on how to do that.

The GenericList2Datatable() method I found on the web. Again google it.

```
public static DataTable GenericList2Datatable<T>(List<T> list)
        {}
```